# Can I use this to dim a 10w LED with an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, led, pwm

Currently I have this and a 12v power supply: http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/High-Power-10W-LED-Driver-MBI6651-PWM-DIM-

I want to dim a 12v 10w LED with PWM.  Is there any way I can do this with an Arduino?

The pin description says this:
PWM terminal. When applied with +5v or suspended, full amount of  current will be output and when connected with ground, output current  will be 0.

So, as the Arduino runs off 5v, does that mean I can use the Arduino PWM to tell this board to DIM? Or I am I getting that totally wrong?

I'm a bit of an electronics noob, so forgive me if these questions are simple.

Comment: This question belongs on http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ugh I'm awful at Arduino AND posting in the right spot :(

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an PWM signal in the Arduino and link it to the  PWM pin in the power supply, it should work as specified in the link.

> PWM terminal. When applied with +5v or suspended, full amount of 
>   current will be output and when connected with ground, output current 
>   will be 0.

So if you generate a full signal, you will have the full power in the power supply, 100% light, 50% PWM will generate 50% power to the LED and so on...

You can check Arduino documentation for more information about how to use the PWM using `analogWrite()`

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PWM

Comment: I use the fade example, and the light just flickers very rapidly.  Plugging it into any pin on the arduino does this.  Without being plugged in, the light is solidly on.  Connecting the pin to ground directly turns the light entirely off.

Comment: When you say, link the PWM Signal in the arduino to the PWM pin in the power supply, what do you mean?

Comment: Your Arduino have some pins with an "~" symbol, those pins are PWM pins, you can use the function AnalogWrite to them, as some examples in the Arduino Tutorial shows.
Your font, have an "EN" (or some other pin name) as an PWM input, you should connect the Arduino PWM OUTPUT to the power supply PWM INPUT, and control it with the code.

Comment: Ohhh.  My power supply only has positive and negative.  But that LED Driver I linked to has a PWM input. Connecting to the PWM input on the driver does nothing.

Comment: @LewisCianci, try to use an potentiometer in the PWM pin of the LED Driver (0 to 5V), and see if it will change the led intensity.